# how to apply animation for CCSprite

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, ccsprite

Am just started one cocos2d game.In that am checking collision and if the collision occurs creating an animation using the following code.Animation code is called but not showing any animation.What is the error with this.Please help me to solve.

```
-(void)check_collision:(ccTime)dt
{
  for(PolygonSprite *sprite in _cache)
  {
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite.boundingBox,monkey.boundingBox))
    {
      if(sprite != monkey)
      {
      NSLog(@"collision collision collision.......%@",sprite);
      id s2 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:1.5 scaleY:1.5];
      id fun = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteDone:)];
      [sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:s2,fun,nil]];
      [self unschedule:@selector(check_collision:)];
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: have u checked that each line of the code is getting executed?

Comment: yes.I put breakpoint and checked it.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
[self schedule:@selector(check_collision:)interval:1];

-(void) check_collision: (ccTime) t
{
   for(PolygonSprite *sprite in _cache)
   {
       if(CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite.boundingBox,monkey.boundingBox))
       {
           if(sprite != monkey)
           {
               id s2 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1 scaleX:2 scaleY:2];
               id fun = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self  selector:@selector(spriteDone)];
               [car.sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:s2,fun,nil]];
               [self unschedule:@selector(check_collision:)];
           }
       }
    }
}

-(void) spriteDone
{
    // Function logic goes here..
}
```

Hope this helps.. Thank you

Comment: working properly at my side buddy. try to run with commenting unschedule.

Comment: @HaveToLearnMore this is different than what you are doing. Show your code for spriteDone ...